# Как написать в беседу, из которой исключили?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Всем привет, два года назад примерно, был такой случай, я исключил из беседы человека, а он все равно имел возможность писать в эту же беседу, я спросил у знакомого программиста, он ответил, что это скрипт специальный, а можно ли щас написать такой скрипт? 
П.С пробовал

```
messages.send(chat_id='id беседы', message='сообщение')
```

В, а пайтон мне выбрасывает ошибку(

спасибо

Comment: конечно же текст ошибки - большой большой секрет

Comment: вот ошибка: "Permission to perform this action is denied: the user was kicked out of the conversation"

Comment: Скорее всего, это был баг, и с тех пор его либо залатали, либо воспроизводится он не так. В любом случае, он может исчезнуть в любой момент. Особенно если информация об этом возникнет здесь.